# Angular 2 Final Release cannot find name module - moduleId: module.id

Tags: angularjs, angular

I just upgraded to the Angular 2 Final Release from RC 4 and I am now getting an error `cannot find name 'module'` on my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dashboard.component.css'],
    styles: ['.chart {display: block; width: 100%;} .title.handle{background-color:transparent;}']

})
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE, this is the error:

```
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "span" ("i role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://BruinAlert.ucla.edu">BruinAlert [ERROR ->]<span class="icon-external-link" /></a></li>
                                    <li role="presentat"): WidgetBankComponent@104:138
    Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "span" ("tion"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="https://logon.ucla.edu/passchange.php">Change Password [ERROR ->]<span class="icon-external-link" /></a></li>
 at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13373:21)
    at eval (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13366:53)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:28)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:43)
    at http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:462:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:368:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:308:25)consoleError @ zone.js:355_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:(…)consoleError @ zone.js:357_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit after updated question:

Your HTML template is incorrect, you have a self-closing span element like this:

`<span class="icon-external-link" />`

which is not allowed in HTML.

Change it to `<span class="icon-external-link"></span>`

---

Before edit:

Are you using the latest angular-cli with Webpack? If yes, you should remove all `moduleId` references, as this upgrade guide describes:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14

> 12. Remove all mention of moduleId: module.id. In webpack, module.id is a number but Angular expect a string.

Comment: I am not sure. How can I tell what version of the angular-cli I am using?

Comment: `ng -v` in the terminal/cmd

Comment: in visual studio, that gives the error 'ng' is not recognizard as the name of a cmdlet, etc

Comment: Are you sure you are using `angular-cli` at all? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: I don't believe so

Comment: just in one of my components

Comment: Have you removed all references to `moduleId` from your code? I can't believe it throws the same error after that

Comment: I have removed them all, but I am still getting `zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:`

Comment: as per your update - unfortunately, that is something I need to ask someone else to fix. I will do that and report back. In the meantime, however, I have a component that does not use `teamplateUrl` but only `styleUrls` and when i take module.id out, it does not throw an error, but the css is not loaded. If that helps at all

Comment: Please create a new question for that issue then. Also consider marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Alright the span errors are gone, now I am getting "unexpected closing <a>". I will try and pinpoint

Comment: Please create a new question and leave this answer as accepted. If can help you in the new question.

Comment: understood. here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006889/angular-2-final-release-promise-rejection-unexpected-closing-tag-a

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it then, should do it for all your components in your app

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dashboard.component.css'],
    styles: ['.chart {display: block; width: 100%;} .title.handle{background-color:transparent;}']

})
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard-component/dashboard-component.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: commenting it out gives me a huge number of zone.js and promise errors

Comment: @blubberbo try just removing it then

Comment: do you have some sort of  `app.module.ts` with a `@NgModule({...}) in your app?

Comment: I do. Not all of my components do, but some of them do. I am using the Angular 2 Final Release

Comment: Ok as long as in your module you import and declare your component, then you should be fine to remove the `moduleId: module.id` from your component(s). See my edited post.

Comment: In my app.module.ts, I import my AppComponent and the 3 other components I have and put them in the `declarations` property. I also removed the module.Id properties from each of the components, but I am still getting the error: `zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:`

Comment: I cannot find anywhere I have module.Id left over. I will try and keep looking

Comment: Ok good! We are getting closer, now this error looks like it could be on a service call or something, check this link out maybe it can help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245168/angular-2-error-unhandled-promise-rejection-template-parse-errors-more-than-o

Comment: I looked more closely at the error, and I believe it is being caused by an external web component on the page (outside of my angular 2 application)

Comment: @blubberbo Could you add the whole Error stack trace to the question, just add an "Update" section below your question with the print out of the error's stack trace. Only giving us a piece of the pie doesn't help us solve the issue when we don't know the whole pie