# Angular 2 Final Release Visual Studio - cannot fine name module, module.id passing incorrect path/causing 404

Tags: angular

I just upgraded to the Angular 2 Final Release (I am using Visual Studio 2015 and TypeScript 1.8) and noticed my line `moduleId: module.id` in my components now has the red squiggly underline and say `cannot find name 'module'`.

In the network tab in Chrome I see that the `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` paths are both incorrect.

This is my working component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dashboard.component.css'],
    styles: ['.chart {display: block; width: 100%;} .title.handle{background-color:transparent;}']

})
```

**But when I remove the line `moduleId: module.id` I get a 404 error because it is looking for:

`http://localhost:56159/dashboard.component.css` and `http://localhost:56159/dashboard.component.html`

Any help would be appreciated!

thank you

Comment: Can you try upgrading your typescript version? According to angular documentation, this is the desired behavior. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

Comment: did you upgrade the angular cli as well?

Comment: @EduardoDennis I am not using the angular cli

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray I will try that, although other developers are also using the machine so I can't do it just yet

Answer (score 0):

try this, giving those two files paths these `./` in front of them

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
    styles: ['.chart {display: block; width: 100%;} .title.handle{background-color:transparent;}']

})
```

Comment: same result `styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],` leads to  `http://localhost:56159/dashboard.component.css`

Answer (score -1):

You will need to reference the Node definition typescript file.
[Node TypeScript Definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts)

As you can see module is defined at line 70

```
declare var module: NodeModule;
```

Comment: interesting - how do I go about referencing this in the Angular 2 Final Release?

Comment: You should install it via typings definition manager. https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: running `npm install typings` installs the typings again, but it does not effect the red squigglies under `moduleId: module.id,`

Comment: typings install dt~node --save --global